# How to check connection to database in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core, database-connection, exists

In normal entity framework I am able to check the database connectivity using `dbContext.Database.Exists()` but in Entity Framework Core it is not there. What is the alternative of `dbContext.Database.Exists()` in Entity Framework Core?

Comment: Do you mean check connection status ?

Comment: I just want to check whether my connection string is valid and It can successfully connect to database.

Comment: You can check Status property in connection instance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can determine whether or not the database is available and can be connected to with the `CanConnect()` method:

```
if (dbContext.Database.CanConnect())
{
    // all good
}
```

You can use `CanConnectAsync()` for asynchronous operation.

Comment: `CanConnect()` applies to Entity Framework Core 2.2 and 3.0 at the time of this comment. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade.canconnect)

Comment: If your server is offline, CanConnect() throws an exception, it doesn't always return true/false. Did you guys notice this?

Comment: @Tony, there was a [recent issue on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18355) about this recently. It should handle exceptions itself and return false instead in the case of a connection failure.

Comment: @nmur I see it, thank you for the reference. It seems like it will be available as of 5.0 and on. We're using 3.1.x and that fix did not make it in time.

Comment: Is there a way to see if I can connect to the **server** (even the DB doesn't exist), for example, would this connection allow me to create the DB should I choose to?

Comment: CanConnect() works fine for version 5.0.
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade.canconnect?view=efcore-5.0

Comment: Checking if we can connect without giving a reason when we can't (to be able to log and understand the problem) makes this method quite useless if you want your system to be robust. It seems that a custom method with a manual try/catch is a better option. The implementation of the CanConnect catches all exceptions and hides them (!!!), this is what we advice developers against doing at all costs because it will usually waste a lot of time later.

Answer (score 6):

Currently (up to the latest at this time EF Core 2.0) the [`DatabaseFacade`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade) class (which is the type of the `DbContext.Database` property) does not expose publicly `Exists` method.

However, the equivalent of the corresponding EF6 method is provided by the EF Core [`IRelationalDatabaseCreator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.irelationaldatabasecreator) service. You can expose it with a custom extension method like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;

public static class DatabaseFacadeExtensions
{
    public static bool Exists(this DatabaseFacade source)
    {
        return source.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>().Exists();
    }
}
```

But please note that the `Exists` method was never intended to check the database connectivity, but rather than check if the database needs to be created (used internally when you call methods like `EnsureCreated`, `Migrate` etc.).

Comment: what do you think is a good method for testing database health? I'm trying to implement one in my load balancer health check.

Comment: How about a:

    await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("SELECT 1");

Comment: @ArcadeRenegade I can't say exactly. I would create (yet another) custom (extension) method and play with the implementation - I envision it more like `OpenConnection` / `CloseConnection` call pair.

Answer (score 1):

The "Exists()" method only check whether the database exists or not, It doesn't really check whether your application can connect to the database or not. For example: if the password is wrong in connection string even then Exists() method will return true.
So according to me, a better solution would be open the connection and check if any exception occurs in that.

```
        try
        {
             dbContext.Database.OpenConnection();
             dbContext.Database.CloseConnection();
             return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

but if you still want to use Exists() then you can use in this way

```
dbContext.Database.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>().Exists();
```